# how to show old prices with red cut lines of products ? magento2

Tags: magento2, price

Hi i want to set new discount price for my products like the image given below , with red cross lines old prices should be cut also new price in below .

[image]

How can i do this in magento2 store ? is there any builtin functionality available for this ? or if u have recommendation i would like to purchase any extension who can do the same thing for my store.

Comment: you need to add the special price for that products and style need to give by css or less.

Comment: you're right can you please paste your comment below as an answer so than i could mark it as right ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

these links below solve my issue :

- https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-special-price-in-magento-2.html
- https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-special-price-configuration-tutorial/